# Newbie A-frame : a-box elements are centred on the x-axis

Tags: d3.js, aframe

I'm trying out a-frame for the first time and simply want to add a number of different sized a-box elements into a scene, all positioned along the x-axis and extending upwards - like buildings on a street for example. If the heights are different - as in the first books of 4 boxes below, the boxes are correctly distributed left to right but vertically the midpoint of their height is centred on the x-axis with half the height going above and half going below the axis. I want each box to start its height from y=0 an extend upwards in the positive y direction to its height.

In the second block of 4 boxes below, they are all the same height and appear as expected.... they are distributed from left to right along the x-axis and extend upwards from y=0 to y=height.

The full code is below. Help appreciated..... I guess its something simple...

'''

```
<a-sky color="#222"></a-sky>
<a-box color="orange" depth="0.1" height="1" width="1"  position="-6 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="orange" depth="0.1" height="2" width="1"  position="-4 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="orange" depth="0.1" height="3" width="1"  position="-2 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="orange" depth="0.1" height="7" width="1"  position="0 0 -10"></a-box>


<a-box color="green" depth="0.1" height="4" width="1"  position="2 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="green" depth="0.1" height="4" width="1"  position="4 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="green" depth="0.1" height="4" width="1"  position="6 0 -10"></a-box>
<a-box color="green" depth="0.1" height="4" width="1"  position="8 0 -10"></a-box>
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documents the position attribute take x,y,z co-ordinates. Where y axis is vertical axis. so you need to change the y axis value. Also you can press `alt + ctrl + i` to open aframe's own inspect tool where you can play around positioning.

Additionally have look at this [glitch code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/curious-handy-freckle).

From the discussion in comments.

You just need to make changes in the position as per the height of first object. When you set position to 0 0 0 the center of that object is placed at 0 0 0, so if your object has height of 5, then your position needs to be 0 2.5 0.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box color="red" depth="1" height="1" width="1" position="0 0 -5"></a-box>
    <a-box color="green" depth="1" height="2" width="1" position="0 3 -5"></a-box>
    <a-box color="blue" depth="1" height="3" width="1" position="0 7 -5"></a-box>
    <a-box color="yellow" depth="1" height="4" width="1" position="0 12 -5"></a-box>
    <a-sky color="#222"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks - yes, I was using x, y, z and was setting y to zero for each box (the second of the 3 position coordinates) and just incrementing x by 0.2 each time so each bar appears 0.2 to the right of the one preceding it. When I try your code, all the bars line up in front of each other as if they're hiding behind each other. Does the code snipet you modified work for you?

Comment: Check now. I've modified the height, width, depth and position attributes.

Comment: thanks for trying again - this time they are aligned on top of each other. They are aligned along the central vertical (y-axis) which makes sense as the x-coord is zero for all the boxes.

Comment: You are welcome. Does this answer your question?

Comment: No - afraid not. Basically the cubes appear correctly (side by side along ground level) only if they are the same height. If they have different heights they no longer appear on ground level but half above and half below ground.

Comment: No worries. you just need to make changes in the position as per the height of first object. When you set position to 0 0 0 the center of that object is placed at 0 0 0, so if your object has height of 5, then your position needs to be 0 2.5 0. try it out. check the glitch link as well. :)

Comment: Ah - ok, that makes sense and matches the behaviour I'm seeing. Will try again and let you know.

Comment: Yeah - got it to work. The approach is subtract the height of the first box and divide the result by 2. Say box 1 has height = 2 and I want to add another box of height 7. Firstly 7 - 2 = 5. Then 5 /2 = 2.5. Thus my box of height 7 should be positioned at 2.5 on the y-axis to render at the same level as box 1. A box of height 4 should be positioned at (4-2)/2 = 1. Great stuff - thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad to know that it worked. Please accept the answer if it was helpful. :)